# Splitting up a sum of matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an indexed family of $p$ different $n×m$ matrices, and $B$ a $m×p$ matrix.

Does the following apply?

$$\require{color}
\sum^p_{i=1} (A_i × B)
\stackrel{?}{=} \left(\sum^p_{i=1} A_i\right) × pB
\color{lightgray} = \left(\sum^p_{i=1} A_i\right) × \left(\sum^p B\right)
$$

or, like it would be for numbers:

$$\require{color}
\sum^p_{i=1} (A_i × B)
\stackrel{?}{=} \left(\sum^p_{i=1} A_i\right) × B
$$

Matrix multiplication is distributive, but different from normal multipkucation, so i have no idea.

Comment: $(A+B)C=AC+AB$ for any matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$ for which the operations make sense. What does $iB$ and $\sum^p B$ stand for? (Obviously, the last equality is not true unless $p=1$, the sum of $A$'s is zero, or $B=0$.)

Comment: ah, sorry: $pB$. it's a scalar multiplication. and $pB = \sum^p B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't even true for numbers.

$$a_1x+a_2x+a_3x=(a_1+a_2+a_3)x$$

And *not*

$$a_1x+a_2x+a_3x=(a_1+a_2+a_3)3x$$

It's not true in general for matrices either. That's just not how distributivity works.

A simple counterexample for matrices:

$$\sum^p_1(Id\ Id)=\sum^p_1Id=p\ Id$$$$\ne\left(\sum^p_1Id\right)p\ Id=p^2Id$$

Non-commutativity doesn't matter, because you can demonstrate

$$\sum^p_{i=1} (A_i × B)=\left(\sum^p_{i=1} A_i\right)B$$

Without ever using commutativity.

Comment: sure, not for numbers. but that non commutative matrix product isn't too much like a number product. the analoguous operation is element wise multiplication. so i simply have no idea how i can decompose above sum (if possible at all)

Comment: @flyingsheep A simple counterexample with matrices is $\sum^p_1(Id\times Id)$.

Comment: so it’s $\sum^p_{i=1} (A_i × B)=\left(\sum^p_{i=1} A_i\right)B$? with $A_i$ and $B$ being matrices? great!